# Do PictureBox controls have another attribute other than .Name for identification

Tags: c#, picturebox

I couldn't find anything here on StackOverflow that answered my question.  I hope I make it clear here.

I've created a windows form application which is the game Yahtzee.  I'm doing it for fun and I'm almost finished.  What I'm trying to accomplish is the following.

When the user wants to save a score for a particular category, they just click on the picturebox that is associated with their category of choice.  Some validation and equations are executed, which is followed by a display() method.  This method logs to the text area of the GUI how many points they just scored.

I am trying to make the logging more easy to read and more meaningful.  Here is the before and after that I'm trying to accomplish.

## current code

...AppendText("\nscored: " + NewYahtzee.Rollscore + " points for " + ((PictureBox)sender).Name)

## current output

scored 50 points for pictureBoxYahtzee

## Output I want

Scored 50 points for your Yahtzee

So I'm trying to replace the name of the control with a friendly/display name.  Is there such an attribute or way of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox(v=vs.110).aspx You could use the Tag property or maybe Text if you're not already using that.

Comment: It is a .NET class like any other.  So just derive your own class from it and add any properties you need to "identify" it.

Comment: If you want a user readable string use Text. For anything more complex, like a structure of strings or whatever use Tag!

Comment: - or - use [current technology](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754130(v=vs.110).aspx) (as opposed to archaic winforms), which has way better support for DataBinding, which allows you to "associate" or "link" a certain UI element with any "piece of data" (or class instance) you need, removing the need for disgusting hacks such as the "Tag" property, or having to create your own UI classes just to allow the UI to hold data.

Comment: The `Text` property of a PictureBox is documented as "This API supports the .NET Framework infrastructure and is not intended to be used directly from your code." As a result I'd avoid it to be on the safe side and use `Tag` as AnotherUser suggested in his answer.

Comment: Thanks all!  I'm going to use the Tag property.  I didn't know it existed.  This is definitely what I'm looking for.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure but I think `.Tag` is a property of `Control`, so any `Control` you have probably has a `.Tag` property that works just the same way. Its very useful to use with list items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As both the commenters above said.

**1.** You could use the `.Tag` property of the `PictureBox`.

When you want to assign some information to the `PictureBox` to hold just do

```
String info = "MyInfo"; 
pictureBox1.Tag = (object)info;
```

The fun thing is, with `.Tag` being a `object` you can box anything into the `.Tag` property. So you could create a custom class filled with info and assign it to the `.Tag`

To retrieve the info you need to make sure that the `.Tag` value is of the same type you assigned it, so following the above example

```
if(pictureBox1.Tag is String)
{
    String info = (String)pictureBox1.Tag;
}
```

**2.** The other option you have is to extend the `PictureBox` class and add public properties to the class.

```
class PictureBoxEx : PictureBox
{
    public String info { get; set; }

    public PictureBoxEx()
    {
    }
}
```

Then find the definition of your `PictureBox` object as it is now and just change its type from `PictureBox` to `PictureBoxEx` and everything should be the same, except now your `PictureBoxEx` reference has the public field `info`.

Answer (score 0):

1)You could make your own derived class like stated above.

2)You could change the name of the control temporarily.

3)You could store it somewhere else(settings perhaps).

I would just add the property to the pictureBox.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, How do I derive the class in this situation?

Comment: See section 2 of my answer. It should be all you need, just create a class in your IDE and pasta that in there, then change whatever `PictureBox` you want to have the property to a `PictureBoxEx` (you'll probably have to build after the class is added).